# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Working on Ubuntu and Python 2.7.6, I am trying to use pip. When I type just `pip` followed by enter, I get:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in  <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 660, in _build_master
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 673, in _build_from_requirements
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Usually the output of `pip` states where a requirement comes from. You should add the full output of `pip` (and format it as code).

Answer (score 10):

Updated for 2017 (Ubuntu 17)

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
pip --version
rm get-pip.py
```

Comment: I was trying to install grpc package using  pip3 install grpc
I had upgraded pip to pip3 recently. Once I inserted the above command to install grpc,  
it was throwing some errors     from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' 
 Then I tried this answer  https://askubuntu.com/questions/969463/python3-pip3-install-broken-on-ubuntu : Dint work for me. After trying your suggestion on getting latest pip with python-ip not python3-pip it worked. with this I dont have to say pip3, i can just say pip.

Comment: `pip --version`

Comment: Pip3 is technically not an upgrade to pip, it is a tool for the python3 language, and pip2 is a tool for the python2 language, so technically they are for different language versions and thus not an upgrade of each other. For example pip2 and pip3 can both be version 18

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with ubuntu 14.04 ,python2.7.6 and pip 1.5.4.
I did this,

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```

To reinstall python (not necessary though)

```
 sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

(removing python pip)

```
 wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
```

(download from this,this is upgraded version (9))

```
 sudo python get-pip.py
 sudo pip install package-name
```

This worked!

Comment: Works but out of date. Added a newer one

Answer (score -3):

You could try the following command

```sh
$ hash -r
```

Comment: And what is that supposed to do? Why would it help?