# The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I have the latest version of pip 8.1.1 on my ubuntu 16.
But I am not able to install any modules via pip as I get this error all the time.

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I found a similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587785/pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-the-pip-1-5-4-distribution-was-not-found), but not helpful.

Comment: what does `pip --version` says for you? Are you in virtualenv?

Comment: @Rohanil: `pip --version` too doesn't work in this case !

Comment: So, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 84):

I repaired mine this with command:

> easy_install pip

Comment: No i dont use virtualenv. Pip version say the same thing

Comment: I tried multiple solutions, including downloading from source, purging, etc. This worked like a charm, thanks! (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: No idea why this worked, but solved it for me on 16.04 as well.

Comment: Not sure if this is a CentOS thing since I'm on AWS ec2-instance but I got `Processing Pip \n error: Not a recognized archive type: pip` so this did not work for me.

Comment: Solved it for me too in Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks

Answer (score 33):

I had this issue for a very long time until I recently found that my 'pip' file (/usr/local/bin/pip) is trying to load the wrong version of pip. I believe you also have 8.1.1 correctly installed on your machine and can give following a try.

1. Open your /usr/local/bin/pip file. For me it looks like :

   ```
   __requires__ = 'pip==9.0.1'
   import sys
   from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       sys.exit(
           load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
   )
   ```
2. Change 'pip==9.0.1' in line 1 and last line to whichever version you have installed on your system, for example you will need to change 7.1.0 to 8.1.1.

Basically /usr/local/bin/pip is an entry file for loading the pip required version module. Somehow when I am upgrading/changing pip installation this file is not getting updated and so I update it manually every time.

Comment: I know this has been a while since being posted, but just had this issue with downloading Kivy, and this worked

Comment: This helped me as well, solving these two cascaded errors:
`pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 8.1.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==7.1.0'))`
`pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: @Nicolas I got a similar issue, but with higher pip versions. So we need a "downgrade" in `/usr/local/bin/pip`, however I do not have it in `Ubuntu 20_04` with `python3.8`. The reason for my conflict was that I played around with the package folders of pip.

Answer (score 16):

Delete all of the pip/pip3 stuff under .local including the packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip python3-pip
```

Now remove all pip3 files from local

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

you can check which pip is installed other wise execute below one to remove all (No worries)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip3.*
```

Using pip and/or pip3, reinstall needed Python packages.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Why installing both `python-pip python3-pip` and not one?

Answer (score 16):

After upgrading from 18.0 to 18.1, I got the same error. Reinstalling the program(without using pip itself) worked for me:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 14):

I did not manage to get it to work by using `easy_install pip` or updating the pip configuration file `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Instead, I removed pip and installed the distribution required by the conf file:

> Uninstalling pip:

`$ sudo apt purge python-pip` or `$ sudo yum remove python-pip`

> Reinstalling required distribution of pip (change the distribution accordingly):

`$ sudo easy_install pip==9.0.3`

Comment: This works for me, although it is on centos6.8. I have python2.6 and python2.7 installed on centos, the problem occurs after I have upgraded pip.

Comment: Neither of these remove commands worked for my on Mac OS. What works for that?

Comment: @Praxiteles have you tried $ sudo pip uninstall pip?

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 4):

On mac this can be fixed with brew

```
brew reinstall python
```

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Catalina with Python 3.7.x.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with Homebrew that occurs when upgrading pip. Working off the answer by @amangpt777, the following worked for me!

You can still access pip by using python -m pip. Hence, you can get your pip version by running:

```
python -m pip --version
```

Copy the version and update the following files with the new version:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.x/bin/pip3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.x/bin/pip3.x
```

They should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3.7
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==21.3.1','console_scripts','pip3.7'
__requires__ = 'pip==21.3.1'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==21.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3.7')()
    )
```

And you should be able to use pip normally again!

Answer (score 2):

if you have 2 versions of pip for example `/usr/lib/pip` and `/usr/local/lib/pip` belongs to python 2.6 and 2.7.
you can delete the `/usr/lib/pip` and make a link pip=>/usr/local/lib/pip.

Answer (score 2):

Just relink to resolve it. Find which python : `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python`

```
ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
```

Or reinstall pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but if easy_install doesn't solve the issue, this worked fine for me:

```sh
$ vim /usr/local/bin/pip
```

Then run:

```
:%s/7\.1\.0/8\.1\.1/g
:wq
```

Answer (score 0):

After a large upgrade in Mint -> 19, my system was a bit weird and I came across this problem too.

I checked the answer from @amangpt777 that may be the one to try

```
/usr/local/bin/pip # -> actually had a shebang calling python3

~/.local/bin/pip* # files were duplicated with the "sudo installed" /usr/local/bin/pip*
```

Running

```
sudo python get-pip.py # with script https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo -H pip install setuptools
```

seem to solve the problem. I understand this as a problem with the root / user installation of python. Not sure if ananconda3 is also messing around with those scrips.