# The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, pip

When I tried to install Jupiter, I got the error :

```
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ sudo -H pip install jupyter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3036, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3049, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 656, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 669, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 854, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

and here what I have when I execute the command `pip --version`, I got

```
pip 9.0.1 from /home/jeremie/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

What could I do to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I am running Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: What Operating System are you running this on?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I am running Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Not sure about the need to install python packages with `sudo`. You may want to manage your packages in a virtual environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845636/the-pip-7-1-0-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo -H pip` is the system pip

> File "/usr/local/bin/pip",

`pip --version` is the pip on your local path

> pip 9.0.1 from /home/jeremie/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Don't use sudo