# Faulty python installation on macOS. How can I repair?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am using macOS High Sierra. In the past at some point I installed Python via brew however for some reason (that I don't know) pip failed to work:

```
$ pip --version Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3195, in <module>
  @_call_aside
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3179, in _call_aside
  f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3208, in _initialize_master_working_set
  working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 683, in _build_master
  return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 696, in _build_from_requirements
  dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 885, in resolve
  raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Hence I issued:

```
$ brew uninstall python@2
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_1... (3,622 files, 50.6MB)
```

After which I was left with what I assume is the default installation of python

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Unfortunately I can't run Python simply by typing `python`:

```
$ python --version
-bash: /usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

however I *can* run that python interpreter by referring to it directly:

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

It bothered me that `python --version` didn't work and I wondered if it was a consequence of previously having had a brew installed version of python on here. Hence I decided to reinstall using `brew install python@2`, which succeeded.

The supposed location of python has changed:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

but I still get the same error when I try to use it:

```
$ python --version
-bash: /usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Of course, using the full path to the python interpreter works fine:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.15
```

Can anyone help me diagnose why simply issuing `python` fails with **`/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin/python: No such file or directory`** even though **`which python`** states that python is located at `/usr/local/bin/python`?

Edit: A responder asked for the output of running `file`, here is that output:

```
$ file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [i386:Mach-O executable i386] [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64]
/usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ file /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Edit: A responder asked for the output of `brew doctor`. Here is that output:

```
Warning: Putting non-prefixed coreutils in your path can cause gmp builds to fail.

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/apm
  /usr/local/bin/atom
```

Edit: Output of PATH, interesting that **/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin** is in there

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
$ ls /usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin': No such file or directory
$ ls /usr/local/opt/python2/libexec
pip  setuptools  wheel
```

Comment: Please check `/usr/bin/python` with `file /usr/bin/python`; what's the output?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thx for the reply. I updated the question with that information.

Comment: Ok, I am not going to pretend I'd know what was going on here :D

Comment: Never mind. You prompted me to include other potentially useful information.

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I edited the question with the output of `brew doctor`

Comment: Thanks, the output of `echo $PATH` will also be useful to determine the priority between the different python installation.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Thanks for responding. I've edited the question with PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is probably simply to remove `/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin` from your `PATH` environment variable.

To do this you have to edit your `~/.bash_profile` and remove the occurence of this directory.

Comment: hmm...looks what's at the top of .bash_profile :) 
`$ head -1 /Users/jamiet/.bash_profile
PATH="/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: I've removed it, and when launch a new shell: `$ python  

Python 2.7.15 (default, May  1 2018, 16:44:08)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>`

Comment: formatting isn't helping, but basically, its working :) thank you so much.