# When I put in pip --version into the terminal I get this error: "The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

Tags: python, django, pip

I put pip --version into the terminal and receive this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
        @_call_aside
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
        ws.require(__requires__)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I'm using Mac

Comment: Does `pip` work for you otherwise? Ie if you do `pip install pandas` does it successfully install Pandas?  And what have you tried so far to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845636/the-pip-7-1-0-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the-application)

Answer (score 2):

Executing:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

should solve this issue.