# How to reinstall python@2 from Homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, python-2.x

I have been having issues with openssl and python@2 with brew, [which have explained here (unresolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229970/aws-cli-errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found). The documented workaround to reinstall Python and openssl was not working, so I decided I would uninstall and reinstall Python.

The problem is, when you try to install Python 2 with brew, you receive this message:

```
brew install python@2
Error: No available formula with the name "python@2"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

python@2 was deleted from homebrew/core in commit 028f11f9e:
  python@2: delete (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/49796)
  EOL 1 January 2020.
  We gave it 1 month more to live so that people had time to migrate.
  All in all, developers had 11 years to do their migration.
  You can use the `brew extract` command and maintain python@2 in your own
  tap if necessary:
  https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap

To show the formula before removal run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" show 028f11f9e^:Formula/python@2.rb

If you still use this formula consider creating your own tap:
  https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap
```

Unfortunately I still have a number of brew formulas that depend on Brew's python@2. Those include `awscli`, `letsencrypt`, pr `sshuttle` for example

```
aws
zsh: /usr/local/bin/aws: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
```

I don't know how to use this `brew extract` command they documented to reinstall Python@2. It needs a formula and a tap. I imagine the formula would be `python@2`. I'm not sure what the tap would need to be.

Additionally reinstalling the taps such as `aws` or `letsencrypt` is not working very well either.

After reinstalling `awscli` (`brew reinstall awscli`), running aws commands still gives errors.

```
aws
/usr/local/Cellar/awscli/2.0.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if x is 0 or x is 1:
/usr/local/Cellar/awscli/2.0.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if x is 0 or x is 1:
/usr/local/Cellar/awscli/2.0.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/usr/local/Cellar/awscli/2.0.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/usr/local/Cellar/awscli/2.0.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jmespath/visitor.py:260: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if original_result is 0:
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: command
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers here, but sadly none of them are reliable nowadays. Save yourself the hassle and just download it from  https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/

Answer (score 181, accepted):

It seems that the homebrew staff really makes it as hard as possible to use Python 2.7 on macOS as they can.

1. The linked `brew extract` link is really not helpful, you need to look for answers here about how to make your own tap from extracted sources.
2. The linked commit: 028f11f9e is wrong, as it contains the already deleted file.
3. The `brew extract` command [doesn't even work correctly](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7057), because of the @ in the package name.

The solution is very simple though, you just need to download the latest known commit and install from that file:

```
cd ~
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/86a44a0a552c673a05f11018459c9f5faae3becc/Formula/python@2.rb
brew install python@2.rb
rm python@2.rb
```

There might be a warning about this being "unstable", which I don't understand as a commit in a Git history is as stable as you can get.

Comment: Just putting the link to the PR here, where python@2 was removed (merged Feb. 4th 2020) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/49796

Comment: @petschki not the answer we asked for, but the answer we wanted to know!

Comment: Thanks, running `brew upgrade python@2` should work too.

Comment: This also helped to fix the following error:

`ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
...`

Comment: This (`brew install <raw url>`) does not seem to work anymore with the current version of Homebrew, it produces the following error: `Error: Calling Installation of python@2 from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract python@2' to stable tap on GitHub instead.`

Comment: This is how I did it:
`cd ~` - `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/86a44a0a552c673a05f11018459c9f5faae3becc/Formula/python@2.rb` - `brew install python@2.rb`

Comment: I just tried the command in this solution and get the error `Error: Calling Installation of python@2 from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract python@2' to stable tap on GitHub instead.`

Comment: @MrTomRod Your solution worked for me. The real answer is always in the comments.

Comment: I updated the answer to the wget based version by @MrTomRod.
The Homebrew team really goes an extra lengh in trying to ban Python 2.7 on macOS: deleting all forum topics mentioning it, deleting GitHub issues, banning GitHub accounts opening an issue and now also blocklisting the commit id in source code.

Comment: I had to do 2 additional things:  `brew uninstall python@2`  before installing the rdb.  If I didn't do that, I was getting errors that it was already installed. Then `brew reinstall openssl@1.1`  After that, my old python code worked again.  Thanks to all above.

Comment: seems like this no longer works on the M1 Mac ... some type of build error ...

Comment: Not working from the last commit...  `==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/2/manifests/2.7.17_1
##O#- #
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Failed to download resource "python@2_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python/2/manifests/2.7.17_1`

Comment: This doesn't work on M1 / Apple Silicon mac as this formula doesn't support it.  It gives the following error: "configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX"  This is likely because brew dropped support for python2 before the M1 was released.

Comment: @hyperknot Given what you listed, the Homebrew team goes way beyond what is acceptable in their attempt to save the world from Python 2. There are reasons to still support Python packages on Python 2, let alone the fact that macOS 11.6 (Big Sur) still includes Python 2.

Comment: Anyone here trying to install Python 2 on the latest release where the system one has been removed entirely, MacOS 12.3 Monterey? This method no longer works. At first `brew` complains about an unrecognized bottle name but even after I comment out the `bottle do` part of the formula, the installation fails with a Python error:
`File "./setup.py", line 805, in detect_modules
    (tuple(int(n) for n in dep_target.split('.')[0:2])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: OK I downloaded from the Python releases page and the installer worked, though the script to install certificates does not. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/

Comment: Got below error while execute brew install python@2.rb

Error: python@2: Invalid bottle tag symbol

Comment: Any solution for this error?  python@2: Invalid bottle tag symbol

Comment: Error: python@2: Invalid bottle tag symbol

Answer (score 379):

You can use `pyenv` to install python with:

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 2.7.18
```

Optionally set it to your global default:

```
pyenv global 2.7.18
```

[Nice article](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) on why using `pyenv` is better than using `brew` to manage your python installation.

To make `python` binary available globally, add shims to PATH:

```
PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH
```

Comment: This worked the best for me after macOS 12.3 Monterey removed python 2.7.

Comment: Sorry for a newbie question but do I get a global `python` or `python2` to work? After following the steps above, `which python` says "python not found". (`which python3` works and it returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`).

Comment: This is a good solution but leaves you without a working /usr/bin/python, which is sometimes required (e.g. whenever it is used under a shebang line - instead of in the /usr/bin/env form)

Comment: Not working in macOS 12.6 Intel) - I had such hope. For the record, binutils is not installed

Comment: I don't recommend this because it tries to build Python from source, which will take forever and possibly fail (as it did for me on my M1 Mac). Plus `pyenv` is one more moving part that you probably don't need.

Comment: I did this and 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'. Worked on my macOS Ventura!

Comment: No support for [t]csh - deal breaker for me.

Comment: brew install pyenv
pyenv install 2.7.18
Worked for me and allowed me to link 'python' to the verison of python i wanted to run by default, thanks.

Comment: Confirmed to work on M2 running Ventura

Comment: @sudo FWIW and for anyone wondering, I added an answer that guides through compiling python2 from source on Apple Silicon

Answer (score 125):

For those showing up here **after Apple removed the system python in macOS 12.3**, here's how to install and run python2 and python3.

**Python 2**

`python`, `python2` -> python 2.7

```
# Download/run the legacy macOS installer (pick which one for your sys)
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/

# Add pip for python2.7
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip2.py
python2 get-pip2.py

# Optionally check for pip updates (in case of post-eol patches)
python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Optionally add the helpers like easy_install back onto your path
# In your ~/.zprofile or whatever bash/shell profile equivalent
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Optionally add some helpers while editing shell profile
alias pip2="python2 -m pip"
alias venv2="virtualenv -p python2"
alias venv3="virtualenv -p python3"

# Optionally some apple-specific std libraries are missing, search
# and download them. Example: plistlib.py
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/2.7/Lib/plistlib.py -o /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py

# Lastly, there is no symlink /usr/bin/python anymore
# /usr/bin is system protected so you can't add one either
# 
# Change your programs to use /usr/local/bin/python
# or google how to disable macOS SIP to make a symlink in /usr/bin
```

**Python 3**

`python3` -> python 3

```
brew update
brew install python3

# Add pip for python 3 in case it is missing
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py

# Check for pip updates
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Optionally add a helper in ~/.zprofile
alias venv3="virtualenv -p python3"
```

**Test it out**

```
~ % python --version
Python 2.7.18

~ % python2 --version
Python 2.7.18

~ % python3 --version
Python 3.9.10

# Running older python2
python2 -m pip install...
python2 ...

# Testing the venv2 alias from above
venv2 foo
source foo/bin/activate
pip -V # pip 20... from... python2.7
pip install -y -r req.txt
pip uninstall -y -r req.txt
pip freeze
deactivate

# Testing the venv3 alias from above
venv3 foo3
source foo3/bin/activate
pip -V # pip22... from ...python3.9
pip install -y -r req.txt
pip uninstall -y -r req.txt
pip freeze
deactivate
```

**Troubleshooting via uninstall / reinstall**

```
# Credit to https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5880/python/uninstall  
# for many of the tips in this section.

# Sometimes there are problems related to accepting xcode 
# tool agreement. Open XCode to make sure it finished 
# installing its tool updates.

# Remove old python Application installs
# open the apps dir and delete Python 2, 3 via Finder
open /Applications

# Remove old brew installs 
brew list | grep python
brew uninstall python
brew uninstall python3

# find/remove lingering unlinked kegs
ls /usr/local/Cellar/ | grep python 

# Cleanup binaries
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Pyth*
rm /usr/local/bin/pip*

# Cleanup symlinks
which -a python # check results, and rm each one
which -a python2 # check results, and rm each one
which -a python3 # check results, and rm each one

brew cleanup # prunes symlinks
```

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal. Thanks much!

Comment: I don't think you need to install pip separately: it comes with the python.org installer. Also, I have the python Framework in my $PATH, and I'm sure I didn't do it manually, so I think that gets done, too.

Comment: You sir, are a genius

Comment: The latest version is now [2.7.18](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) but this was the guide that I needed, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Josh Hibschman, I followed your steps for 2.7 and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 60):

## How to install `python@2` from a local tap

The following method works with the current version (`c9b8a3ef6`) of `brew`:

```
$ brew tap-new <user>/homebrew-python2
$ brew extract python@2 <user>/homebrew-python2
$ brew install /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/<user>/homebrew-python2/Formula/python@2.7.17.rb
```

The `brew tap-new` command creates a new local tap template in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/<user>/homebrew-python2`. The tap name needs a `<user>` and a `<repo>` component separated by a `/`. The actual values are arbitrary. The naming above follows the conventions from [How to Create and Maintain a Tap](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap). If you wanted to push the tap to GitHub you would use your GitHub username as user. Pushing to GitHub is not necessary (and was not performed in the instructions above).

The `brew extract` commands extracts the recent version of formula from the repos history into the given (local) tap. In our case `python@2.7.17.rb` is extracted.

The `brew install` command finally installs the formula.

## Why is this necessary?

The method discussed above (installing an old version of the formula from a GitHub commit URL) does not work anymore for `python@2` with the current version of `brew` (`c9b8a3ef6`), it produces the following error:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/86a44a0a552c673a05f11018459c9f5faae3becc/Formula/python@2.rb
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated Homebrew from 88f17b8b6 to c9b8a3ef6.
...
Error: Calling Installation of python@2 from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract python@2' to stable tap on GitHub instead.
```

Comment: This was helpful as I was trying to install an old version of openssl. One note: `<user>` in the example above is your Github username.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer.  <user> does not have to be your github username; it can be anything or nothing.  Using your login name on your local machine is a good way to not have it collide with other users on your computer, if any.

Comment: This should be the answer since the accepted answer is no longer working.

Comment: These instructions don't work for me unfortunately. When attempting `brew extract python@2 <user>/homebrew-python2`, I get: *Error: python@2: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass*

Answer (score 18):

Please check following command (I am using it on macOS 10.13, it is possible that for a newer macOS it will work without source compilation):

```
brew install pr0d1r2/python2/python@2.7.17 --build-from-source
```

Comment: This worked but this also reinstalled my Python3. Which means it removed all the packages I had installed with it.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 11):

this work for me on m1(12.3.1):
dont use brew, download from [python official website](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/) directly.
This question has tortured me for a long time :(

Comment: @Dos This nonetheless provides an answer to the _underlying problem_; please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This solved my problem. Really simple, thaks

Answer (score 5):

For posterity, working on macOS 10.15 (May/2021):

```
/usr/local/bin/brew tap-new ${USER}/homebrew-python2

/usr/local/bin/brew extract python@2 ${USER}/homebrew-python2

/usr/local/bin/brew install /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/${USER}/homebrew-python2/Formula/python@2.7.17.rb

# https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5734#issuecomment-464705002
/usr/local/bin/brew untap ${USER}/python2
```

Answer (score 3):

Not about using Homebrew, but [`asdf-python`](https://github.com/danhper/asdf-python) worked for me flawlessly as I was able to install and use Python `2.7.18` from it. (The top-voted answer seems to fail on my system, M1 Max MBP with MacOS 12.3. A few other answers also seem convoluted and didn't work.)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want make python2 work on Mac the most effective way is access https://www.python.org/downloads/ and download the pkg of this version of python.

Seems that homebrew doesn`t support python2 anymore.

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers on this page worked for me<sup>1</sup> in MacOS Monterey. In case this helps anyone, here is an alternative solution, *which is not technically installed directly via Homebrew* – just indirectly.

A simple solution for me, that works, is to install **Anaconda** via Homewbrew, and then create a virtual environment for Python 2.7.

Note: Installing Anaconda will take up some space on your computer, moreso than just simply installing Python 2.7 via Homebrew or Pyenv:

> Anaconda is a distribution of the Python and R programming languages
> for scientific computing (data science, machine learning applications,
> large-scale data processing, predictive analytics, etc.), that aims to
> simplify package management and deployment. The distribution includes data-science packages suitable for Windows, Linux, and macOS.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)

Very basically, the steps are as follows – but you may want to refer to a full install guide for more details.

Install Anaconda from Homebrew:

```
brew install --cask anaconda
```

When installed, create a virtual environment for Python 2.7 in a folder of your choice, in this case for  Python 2.7.18:

```
conda create --prefix=/MY_FOLDER/NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT python=2.7.18
```

You can list the environments:

```
conda env list
```

Activate the environment via:

```
conda activate NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT
```

Now you can install packages, etc, as usual, using `pip install <package>` or alternatively `conda install <package>`.

NB: If your Anaconda install is fresh,

1. You may be prompted to run `conda init` once before you can activate the virtual environment.
2. You may have to run the below in order to be able to find the virtual environment (e.g. via `conda list env`) which will add a line in `~/.condarc`:

   `conda config --append envs_dirs /MY_FOLDER/NAME_OF_ENVIRONMENT`
3. If you are annoyed by the text which may say "Py base" whenever you open Terminal, do the following per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57642532/4909923), which will add a line in `~/.condarc`:

   `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`
4. Once you have activated the environment, to shorten the path to it that appears in Terminal whenever it is active, add this row to `~/.condarc`:

   `env_prompt: ({name})`

---

<sup>1</sup> I am not sure if it is because something relating to Python installs is broken on my Mac – so you may not have the same issues. But I was running into problems with all the solutions: everything from installing `virtualenv` for the native MacOS Python install did not succeed, build error when attempting to install 2.7.18 via `pyenv`, the `brew extract` method also failed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work!!!

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
pip install virtualenv # This will not work, use below
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/pip  install virtualenv
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python venv_twisted
source venv_twisted/bin/activate
```

Comment: There are **seven existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **one hundred fifty votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Highly voted answers may become obsolete over time and prompt the need for new, entirely different answers. The "there's already a highly upvoted answer" argument is generally a poor one.

Comment: @awwright: Reread my critique. It's not that the highly voted answer must be correct. It's that this answer was submitted to a question without any explanation. If the top-voted answer is out-of-date, and this addresses that, then this answer should state that clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I used methods from this page to install Python 2.7 on Mac for a year.
But May 2021 I tried most suggestions on this page and they all failed.

Maybe Python 2.7 is getting harder to install or maybe my new macOS Big Sur 11.4 is causing the problem.

I was able to setup a working Python 2.7 environment in this way by reusing the native Python 2.7.16

- Install pip manually
- Setup a virtual environment
- Install dependencies with pip in virtual environment

Here are the install steps:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
pip install virtualenv
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/pip  install virtualenv
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: Where does `virtualenv` get installed using this method? I get `command not found: virtualenv` although it appears to have been installed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors using brew and not able to install.

**Error: Installation of python@2 from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! brew extract python@2 to a stable tap on GitHub instead.**

You can direct download python from their site [version 2.7.18](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) and for list of available version [click here](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/)

Comment: Even though this is not what this questions is looking for, to my understanding, I am not sure why this answer was -1, since currently this is a solution to the problem to install python2 in mac OSs.

Answer (score 0):

##### Use case

None of the existing answers really worked for me, so here's my solution in case someone else has a similar use case.

I have `python3` installed via homebrew which is symlinked as `python` and I wanted `python2` to exist alongside it without changing anything.

##### Overview and some notes

- **Compiling from source**: At the end of the day, it was easier to compile from source. So this solution assumes you have `gcc` installed, which you can do via `homebrew install gcc`
- **Sane dependencies**: You will also need zlib and other dependencies installed via `brew install openssl bzip2 libffi readline sqlite xz zlib`
- **Architecture**: I'm on Apple Silicon so I needed the `arch` command below, but you should be able to omit it if running on x86. If you're also on Apple Silicon, you'll need Rosetta to be available, otherwise install it with `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`
- **Optimizations**: I also think you can also remove the `--enable-optimizations` flag from `./configure...` if you want faster compilation at the expense of not having optimizations, but I haven't tested it.
- **The most important bit is running `make altinstall` at the end instead of `make install`, which ensures your existing `python` is left untouched.**
- **Timing consideration**: The process *will* take quite a while to complete even on fast machines. I'm on a M2 Ultra and `configure` took a few mins whereas `make` took several minutes (long enough to let me write this whole answer!)
- **About `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`**: These environment variables help the `configure` script locate necessary libraries for Python features. Setting these ensures your Python build can support secure networking, data compression, and more.
- **Clean Build Environment**: Running `make clean` ensures that any previous compilation attempts are cleared out, providing a clean slate for a successful build.

##### Downloading and extracting Python 2.7

I suggest `cd`'ing into some dir like `~/Downloads` before running the below

```
brew install zlib openssl bzip2 libffi readline sqlite xz 
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-2.7.18.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.18
```

##### Run the Install Script

Before installing, you need to manually change to a Rosetta shell by typing

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh
```

You'll need to do this each time you open a new terminal session and intend to run any part of the installation process under Rosetta on Apple Silicon.

After doing that, you're free to run the install script.

I've pasted this separately from the download script (which you'll only ever need to run once) in case the below fails for some reason:

```
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib -L$(brew --prefix libffi)/lib -L$(brew --prefix xz)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix libffi)/include -I$(brew --prefix xz)/include -I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include"
./configure --prefix=/opt/python27 --enable-optimizations
make clean
sudo make altinstall
sudo ln -s /opt/python27/bin/python2.7 /opt/python27/bin/python2
echo 'export PATH="/opt/python27/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

##### Verification

You can now run:

- `which python2`, which should point to `/opt/python27/bin/python2`
- `python2 --version`, which should confirm the installation by showing `Python 2.7.18`

##### Installing pip and setuptools

You'll need to install old (and possibly unsafe) versions of pip and setuptools, sorry

```
sudo chown -R $(`echo whoami`):staff /opt/python27/
curl -O https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/40/4e00501c204b457f10fe410da0c97537214b2265247bc9a5bc6edd55b9e4/setuptools-44.1.1.zip
curl -O https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/7f/55721ad0501a9076dbc354cc8c63ffc2d6f1ef360f49ad0fbcce19d68538/pip-20.3.4.tar.gz
tar -xf setuptools-44.1.1.zip
tar -xf pip-20.3.4.tar.gz
cd setuptools-44.1.1
python2 setup.py install
cd ../pip-20.3.4
python2 setup.py install
```