# Cannot install python2 using brew install python@2

Tags: python, homebrew, python-2.x

I am trying to install python2 using:

```
brew install python@2
```

These are the results I get:

```
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "pip2".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

According to my research, python2 was removed from brew. I also ran:

```
brew search python
```

I got the following results:

```
==> Formulae
app-engine-python         micropython               python@3.9
boost-python              python-markdown           reorder-python-imports
boost-python3             python-yq                 wxpython
gst-python                python@3.7
ipython                   python@3.8 ✔
==> Casks
awips-python              kk7ds-python-runtime      mysql-connector-python
```

**My question is:**
Is there another good way to download python2?

Comment: You should not install Python2. Use Python3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brew - reinstalling python@2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298514/brew-reinstalling-python2)

Comment: _Is there another good way to download python2?_ Have you done any research?

Answer (score 4):

You can download the last release of python 2 [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/) but notice that python2 is already in End Of Life state and **no longer supported**.

Answer (score 1):

You could just download it from the website and use the GUI installer. https://www.python.org/downloads/