# Textmate latex compilation : pb with python version after macOS update Monterey 12.3

Tags: python, ruby, latex, textmate

I use textmate for make pdf file in latex. After the update of macOS Monterey version 12.3, the minimal version of python (/usr/bin/python) has disappeared : the compilation don't work now.
I try to change in the textmate's files /usr/bin/python by /usr/bin/python3 (I have only this python folder) but that always don't work.

the error say me ti change the compilation command which is this :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby18
# coding: utf-8

require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/process"
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/htmloutput"
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/save_current_document"

# To enable the typesetting of unsaved documents, you must change the “Save” setting of
# this command to “Current File” and add the variable TM_LATEX_AUTOSAVE to TextMate's
# Shell Variables preferences. Be warned that your document must be encoded as UTF-8 if
# you exercise this option — becauseTextMate.save_current_document cannot know the file 
# encoding you prefer.

TextMate.save_current_document unless ENV["TM_LATEX_AUTOSAVE"].nil?

texmate = ENV["TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT"] + "/bin/texmate.py"
engine_version = TextMate::Process.run(texmate, "version")
TextMate::HTMLOutput.show(:title => "Typesetting “#{ENV["TM_DISPLAYNAME"] || File.basename(ENV["TM_FILEPATH"])}”…", :sub_title => engine_version) do |io|
  TextMate::Process.run(texmate, 'latex', :interactive_input => false) do |line|
    io << line
  end
end
::Process.exit($?.exitstatus || 0) # exitstatus is nil if our process is prematurely terminated (SIGINT)
```

Thank you very much for your help.
PS : The compilation work with texshop, I don't think it is a latex problem

Comment: Many legacy python-based applications won't work with 3... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71513250/786389 to get python2 back

Comment: The need to install pyobjc was the piece of information I really needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaTeX-Bundle of TextMate was not updated in time for the release of MacOS 12.3. You can fix it as follows:

1. Download and install Python 3 (https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pyobjc --user
3. cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin
4. Change “python” to “python3” in the header of all .py files (configure.py, btexdoc.py, texmate.py, texparser.py)

Comment: A big thank you to Felix Brandt, my texmate work great now and I am very happy :-). I don't think without you I will solve my problem. it's very nice.

Answer (score -2):

I just found the following page:
https://www.heise.de/news/macOS-12-3-Apple-wirft-Python-raus-6341999.html
which told me that Apple does not support Python (and some other script languages like for instance Perl) any further. The last version they supported was Python 2.7.
Developers should install (and care for) Python 3 by themselves.
The Python page told exactly the same thing:

https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/