# setting up Textmate for latex on Mac OS 12.6

Tags: python, macos, textmate, textmatebundles

I believe my question is similar to the following question---but I'm unsure what to do:
[python and textmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511514/textmate-latex-compilation-pb-with-python-version-after-macos-update-monterey)

I am trying to set up textmate to use on a new Mac OS 12.6.  One key step is to go to Bundle, Preferences, and change settings there.  However, when I do this, I get the following error:

> Preferences…: /Users/amfriede/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin/configure.py: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I gather from the other answer that I am supposed to download Python 3 (done!) and somehow redirect TextMate to python 3 (that now sits in an applications folder). However, I'm a bit sketchy on how to do this last step.

Comment: Use `Sublime Text` instead ;)

Comment: That’s perfectly legit! 

Comment: To be honest, I had some adventure with `TextMate` + `LaTeX` in the past, but I'd still suggest `LyX` - as a first choice when it comes to running `LaTeX` editor at `macOS`: https://www.owsiak.org/latex-on-macos-high-sierra/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I learned:

1. Download and install Python 3 (https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. In terminal type: /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pyobjc --user
3. In terminal type: cd ~/Library/Application\
4. In terminal type: ls
   This last step will list a bunch of things of the form xx.py. For each one, type
   mate xx.py
   a file opens and there you change python to python3, save, close, go on to the next.  Once you have gone through every file of the form xx.py, you can proceed to set up Textmate for latex as you normally would.