# Pb latex compilation with Textmate under OS Ventura 13

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, textmatebundles

I have some problem to generate pdf file after calling `pdflatex` under TextMate. I work under Mac OS 13 and I know that The LaTeX-Bundle of TextMate was not updated in time for the release of MacOS 12.3. So I followed the procedure here : [Textmate latex compilation : pb with python version after macOS update Monterey 12.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71511514/7445958)

but I have problem with parsing.py.
I have this message at the end (when the compilation stops) :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/jimmy/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin/texmate.py", line 1014, in status = command_parser.parse_stream() 
File "/Users/jimmy/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 770, in parse_stream return super(LaTexMkParser, self).parse_stream() 
File "/Users/jimmy/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 187, in parse_stream function(matching, line) 
File "/Users/jimmy/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 789, in start_latex fatal_error, number_errors, number_warnings = parser.parse_stream() 
File "/Users/jimmy/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 610, in parse_stream return super(LaTexParser, self).parse_stream() 
File "/Users/jimmy/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 194, in parse_stream line = self.get_rewrapped_line() 
File "/Users/jimmy/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/Python/parsing.py", line 139, in get_rewrapped_line line = to_utf8(self.input_stream.readline()) 
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 92: invalid continuation byte
```

Thank you very much for your help.
**PS** : The compilation works with `texshop`, I don't think it is a latex problem

I fixed it as follows:

- `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pyobjc --user`
- `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin`
- Change “python” to “python3” in the header of all .py files (configure.py, btexdoc.py, texmate.py, texparser.py)

But I still have a problem...

Comment: Same here, some .tex files produce that parsing error, while other compile just fine. I do believe everything is UTF8 in my setup, so I don't know why this error would arise. this is especially frustrating, since -- if I'm not mistaken -- the code involved is only used by TextMate to parse the log files...

Answer (score 1):

This issue has now been solved in [issue #198 of latex.tmbundle's github](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues/198).

> As far as I can tell the problem was fixed in the latest version of the Bundle in the repository. At least I was not able to reproduce the problem using the steps provided in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to rename the python binary in the mentioned directory

`~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin`

from "python" to "python3".