# Python not found for node-gyp

Tags: python, node.js, macos, npm, node-gyp

I am trying to `npm install` for a project in my mac but for some reason it says python not found even though `python3` command is working fine and I also set alias python to python3 in by `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bash-profile` and restarted several times but still the same issue.

Screenshot of the issue.

[image]

### **NOTE:** See comments for the solution

Comment: try: `npm config set python C:\Library\Python\Python310\python.exe`  via administrator

Comment: @debugger I am talking about mac

Comment: try same cmd for mac aswell. Check your python lib path and try

Comment: now getting this error `stack Error: Command failed: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];`

Comment: @debugger Do I need to intall python2 to make it work?

Comment: try: python 2.7

Comment: @debugger thanks I installed python 2.7 taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71513250/13509950) and it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that Python is required in the system path to operate this command. Solutions:

1. [Install `pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation)
2. Install either Python 2.7 or Python 3.x: `pyenv install 2.7.18` or `pyenv install 3.9.11` (for example)
3. If you have more than one python version, ensure one of them is set as global: `pyenv global 3.9.11`
4. **Add `pyenv` to your system path**

   - On Mac, put this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`: `export PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH`, then run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`
   - For Windows, try `npm config set python C:\Library\Python\Python310\python.exe` (for example) via administrator
5. Run `npm install` again