# npm install issue with python 3 in macos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, homebrew, npm-install

I've cloned a reactJs repository and after that, I wanted to run the " npm install " but when I was running it I got Syntax Error about using python

error code:

```
stack Error: Command failed: /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 -c import sys; print 
"%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:446:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:686:12)
```

Comment: That code was evidently written for Python 2.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, your right, but the problem is homebrew does not have python 2 anymore, I just found python 3

because my MacBook has M1 Chip

Comment: macOS system Python (`/usr/bin/python`) is v2.

Comment: @robertklep 

$> cd /usr/bin/python   
 --------------------
cd: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/python

Comment: @robertklep not since 12.3

Comment: You could update the code from Python 2 to Python 3 (and create a pull request).

Comment: Hmm I'm still on 12.2…

Comment: @robertklep so how can I execute it?

Comment: @jabaa how can I update it?

Comment: @DanielEf never mind, if you're on 12.3, apparently it doesn't exist anymore :( You may be able to find it still in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` but I'd expect it to be removed from there as well. You can try and use `pyenv` though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274521

Comment: Fix the code. It's written for Python 2. Rewrite it to Python 3.

Comment: @robertklep I tried pyenv but it's not working too and it says python2 is not compatible with my CPU type

Comment: How large is the actual? Is it a dozen of lines containing `print` statements that have to be fixed or a codebase with millions of lines with complex code? Updating a simple script can be the easiest and quickest fix. Python 2 is dead.

Comment: @jabaa cant get you, which scripts should update?

Comment: The script that contains `print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]` should be updated to `print("%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3])`

Comment: @jabaa where can I change this script?

Comment: You're trying to install an outdated package. Find out which package it is. Find that line in the package. Fix it. Either create a pull request or fork the project. Use the fixed package. That's how open source works.