# error when installing tensorflow with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I tried to install TensorFlow on Ubuntu using `pip install tensorflow` but it gave me this error

```html
   moo</font>@moo-desktop> pip install tensorflow
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-2.8.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (497.6 MB)
Collecting tf-estimator-nightly==2.8.0.dev2021122109
  Using cached tf_estimator_nightly-2.8.0.dev2021122109-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six&gt;=1.12.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (1.14.0)
Collecting libclang&gt;=9.0.1
  Using cached libclang-13.0.0-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
Collecting typing-extensions&gt;=3.6.6
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting absl-py&gt;=0.4.0
  Using cached absl_py-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting gast&gt;=0.2.1
  Using cached gast-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy&gt;=1.20 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (1.21.4)
Collecting tensorboard&lt;2.9,&gt;=2.8
  Using cached tensorboard-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem&gt;=0.23.1
  Using cached tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting grpcio&lt;2.0,&gt;=1.24.3
  Using cached grpcio-1.43.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.1 MB)
Collecting h5py&gt;=2.9.0
  Using cached h5py-3.6.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
Collecting opt-einsum&gt;=2.3.2
  Using cached opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow) (45.2.0)
Collecting protobuf&gt;=3.9.2
  Using cached protobuf-3.19.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wrapt&gt;=1.11.0
  Using cached wrapt-1.13.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (84 kB)
Collecting keras-preprocessing&gt;=1.1.1
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers&gt;=1.12
  Using cached flatbuffers-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting astunparse&gt;=1.6.0
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting google-pasta&gt;=0.1.1
  Using cached google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting termcolor&gt;=1.1.0
  Using cached termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  <font color="#CC0000"><b>error</b></font>: <b>subprocess-exited-with-error</b>
  
  <font color="#CC0000">×</font> <font color="#4E9A06">python setup.py egg_info</font> did not run successfully.
  <font color="#CC0000">│</font> exit code: <font color="#06989A"><b>1</b></font>
  <font color="#CC0000">╰─&gt;</font> <font color="#CC0000">[20 lines of output]</font>
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font> Traceback (most recent call last):
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;&lt;string&gt;&quot;, line 2, in &lt;module&gt;
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;&lt;pip-setuptools-caller&gt;&quot;, line 34, in &lt;module&gt;
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/tmp/pip-install-p4b76c4_/termcolor_58302b6ceeac4cefa16f556d214c21da/setup.py&quot;, line 37, in &lt;module&gt;
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     setup(name=&apos;termcolor&apos;,
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py&quot;, line 108, in setup
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py&quot;, line 447, in __init__
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     _Distribution.__init__(self, {
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py&quot;, line 292, in __init__
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     self.finalize_options()
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py&quot;, line 740, in finalize_options
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     ep.load()(self)
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py&quot;, line 2444, in load
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py&quot;, line 2467, in require
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>   File &quot;/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py&quot;, line 787, in resolve
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font>     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The &apos;packaging&gt;=20.0&apos; distribution was not found and is required by the application
  <font color="#CC0000">   </font> <font color="#CC0000">[end of output]</font>
  
  <font color="#75507B"><b>note</b></font>: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
<font color="#CC0000"><b>error</b></font>: <b>metadata-generation-failed</b>

<font color="#CC0000">×</font> Encountered error while generating package metadata.
<font color="#CC0000">╰─&gt;</font> See above for output.

<font color="#75507B"><b>note</b></font>: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
<font color="#06989A"><b>hint</b></font>: See above for details.
</pre>
```

I update pip to the last version but it didn't work any idea how to resolve the error

Comment: try using `pip3 install tensorflow` insteadlly

Comment: @mariolu why do you expect that this would change anything. Looking at the error message, ti is clear that python3.8 is used for the installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure you have the latest versions without compatibily issues: you may try:
Uninstalling pip:

$ sudo apt purge python-pip or $ sudo yum remove python-pip

Reinstalling required distribution of pip (change the distribution accordingly):

$ sudo easy_install pip==9.0.3
and refer to this [issue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845636/the-pip-7-1-0-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the-application)