# PIP issue in Ubuntu 18.04 (pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==10.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04

After upgrading your Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to the latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, while using `pip` or `pip3` facing [this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwHh3.png):

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==10.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: In case it helps: In my case this problem was solved by adding "universe" to apt sources (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061488/865083))

Answer (score 2):

**What seems to solve the problem.**
Firstly, removing `pip` from the computer by `sudo apt-get purge python-pip`
and then again reinstalling it by `apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential` or just `sudo apt-get install python-pip` wont fix the error. Because `pip-9.0.1` is being installed by default.

**Actual solution**
Installing using curl helped,
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
and then `python get-pip.py` for python 2 and `python3 get-pip.py` for python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
pip --version
rm get-pip.py
```

Above shell command works for me!
For details, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887255/8596899